# How to have an empty first row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in this format:

```
how
to
have
an
empty
first
row
```

How do i make it become this such that the first row is empty followed by my data afterwards:

```
     #blank row (I dont want it to be None or "" or [], i just want it to be an empty row)
how
to
have
an
empty
first
row
```

Comment: What is column name? What it reason for empty row?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution (Just change 'inserted' to '', for an empty string. If using numbers use np.nan):

```
pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 0, values=['inserted'], axis=0)).rename(columns ={0:'col1'})

    col1
    0   inserted
    1   how
    2   to
    3   have
    4   an
    5   empty
    6   first
    7   row
```

You can set where (which row) you want the value to be inserted into:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, 5, values=['inserted'], axis=0)).rename(columns ={0:'col1'})
col1
0   how
1   to
2   have
3   an
4   empty
5   inserted
6   first
7   row
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['']}).append(df, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
     col
0       
1    how
2     to
3   have
4     an
5  empty
6  first
7    row
```